# Windows posix sockets performance

Tags: windows, sockets, serversocket

I am looking for information on Windows network programming.  Mainly how to get a single executable to cope with 1000 connections.

We use select() FD_ISSET etc on unix and this works very quick.   On Windows these APIs are very poor.   FD_SET is lots slower but even when working around this, Windows is lots slower than HPUX.

I'm looking for a win32 API call which I can use instead of the select() call which doesnt require so much CPU/time.  Currently we spend 50% of the time (and CPU) in select(), where as on unix the time spent in send() and recv(), which is what I would expect.

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [**Windows I/O Completion Ports**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here's an [article](http://doc.sch130.nsc.ru/www.sysinternals.com/ntw2k/info/comport.shtml) from [SysInternals](http://doc.sch130.nsc.ru/www.sysinternals.com/index.shtml) guys.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need.    The main thing I have to decide now is should I reimplement the server with I/O Completion Ports or using java (as we already have 50% of our servers running java and 50% c legacy programs)   I love inheriting 30 year old code and being told to fix a Windows performance issue :)

Comment: Other useful links - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198.aspx - http://int64.org/2009/05/13/high-performance-io-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

If you are really into the scalable sockets programming, nothing would outperform IO completion ports on Windows.

Having said this, you program would likely need a big rewrite for  completion ports model.

However, it is possible to improve performance even with select()/FD_ISSET.

Here is how it can be done:
in winsock2.h fd_set  is defined as an array of SOCKETs and a element counter

```
typedef struct fd_set {
    u_int fd_count;               /* how many are SET? */
    SOCKET  fd_array[FD_SETSIZE];   /* an array of SOCKETs */
} fd_set;
```

Also in winsock2.h you'll find that FD_SET adds a SOCKET at the end of this array, and FD_ISSET is doing a linear search in the array.

Now if you change macros to use sorted array of SOCKETs, i.e

- FD_SET adds sockets in the sorted order
- FD_ISSET does binary search instead of linear

then dependent on the size of the array FD_ISSET can be greatly improved (while performance of FD_SET will degrade somewhat, but we're assuming that FD_SET is a seldom operation).

On Unixes, performance of select() is better since they  FD_SET as bitmap, FD_SET/FD_ISSET would just test or set a bit. On Windows this technique would not be applicable because socket is not a small positive file descriptor number, it is a HANDLE and scalar value of a handle can be large.

Comment: I have used this type of 'fix' to get the performance from 360s to just 30s, but this is still so much slower than the 1 or 2 seconds HPUX takes.  It did remove quite a lot of n squared sections of the code.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a klugde, and a good solution would do async io a la completion ports.  WSAPoll() (akin to Unix poll(), available since Vista) may be worth investigation - though I recall it was rather slow when it was first released - slower than "optimized" select() in my tests. It is possible that it was  improved since.