# How do I get socket (in.h) header files from mingw?

Tags: c++, mingw, posix

I'd like to get the socket and other posix headers and libraries.
How do I get them?
Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Headers alone won't do you any good. You will need a complete sockets library as well.

Unfortunately, there isn't really a "POSIX socket" library for Windows.

You need to use the WinSock library.

You may find this thread of use too:
[Windows posix sockets performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965512/windows-posix-sockets-performance)